# Django : TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Driver'

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

When creating vehicle, in driver_id, I must pass an instance of an object Drive (so when I pass a number, I find an object with this ID in the serializer and pass it, because otherwise it would give an error that an instance needs to be passed).

But when I want to display information on some object vehicle/1/, it will give an error if this object has a driver_id field of an object instance, But when it is null, then everything is fine

Vehicle Model:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    driver_id = models.ForeignKey(Driver,
                                  related_name='vehicles',
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  null=True,
                                  blank=True)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Model')
    plate_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Plate Number')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('vehicle/', VehicleListView.as_view()),
    path('vehicle/<int:vehicle_id>/', VehicleView.as_view())
]
```

```
class VehicleListView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        vehicles = Vehicle.objects.all()
        serializer = VehicleSerializer(vehicles, many=True)
        return Response({"vehicles": serializer.data})

    def post(self, request):
        vehicles = request.data.get('vehicle')
        serializer = VehicleSerializer(data=vehicles)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            vehicle_saved = serializer.save()
        context = {
            'success': f'Vehicle {vehicle_saved.plate_number} created successfully'
        }
        return Response(context)
```

```
class VehicleView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, vehicle_id):
        vehicle = Vehicle.objects.filter(id=vehicle_id)
        serializer = VehicleSerializer(vehicle, many=True)
        return Response({"vehicle": serializer.data})

    def put(self, request, vehicle_id):
        vehicle_saved = get_object_or_404(Vehicle.objects.all(), pk=vehicle_id)
        data = request.data.get('vehicle')
        serializer = VehicleSerializer(instance=vehicle_saved, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            vehicle_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": f"Vehicle '{vehicle_saved.plate_number}' updated successfully"
        })

    def delete(self, request, vehicle_id):
        vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle.objects.all(), pk=vehicle_id)
        vehicle.delete()
        return Response({
            "message": f"Vehicle with id `{vehicle_id}` has been deleted."
        }, status=204)
```

```
class VehicleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    driver_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    make = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    model = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    plate_number = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data['driver_id'] = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id'])
        return Vehicle.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if "driver_id" in validated_data:
            instance.driver_id = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id'])
        instance.make = validated_data.get('make', instance.make)
        instance.model = validated_data.get('model', instance.model)
        instance.plate_number = validated_data.get('plate_number', instance.plate_number)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Driver Model:

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Last Name')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Created')
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Driver Views:

```
class DriverView(APIView):
    def get(self, request,  driver_id):
        driver = Driver.objects.filter(id=driver_id)
        serializer = DriverSerializer(driver, many=True)
        return Response({"driver": serializer.data})

    def put(self, request, driver_id):
        saved_driver = get_object_or_404(Driver.objects.all(), pk=driver_id)
        data = request.data.get('driver')

        serializer = DriverSerializer(instance=saved_driver, data=data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            saved_driver = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            "success": f"Driver '{saved_driver.first_name}' updated successfully"
        })

    def delete(self, request, driver_id):
        driver = get_object_or_404(Driver.objects.all(), pk=driver_id)
        driver.delete()
        return Response({
            "message": f"Driver with id `{driver_id}` has been deleted."
        }, status=204)


class DriverListView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        qp = request.query_params

        if not qp:
            drivers = Driver.objects.all()
        else:
            created_gte, created_lte = 'created_at__gte', 'created_at__lte'

            timezone = created_gte if created_gte in qp else created_lte

            time = qp.get(timezone)
            time = map(int, time.split('-')[::-1])

            if timezone == created_gte:
                drivers = Driver.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime(*time))
            else:
                drivers = Driver.objects.filter(created_at__lte=datetime(*time))

        serializer = DriverSerializer(drivers, many=True)
        return Response({"driver": serializer.data})

    def post(self, request):
        drivers = request.data.get('driver')
        serializer = DriverSerializer(data=drivers)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            driver_saved = serializer.save()
        return Response({
            'success': f'Driver {driver_saved.first_name} created successfully'
        })
```

Driver Serializer:

```
class DriverSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Driver.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)

        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Request:

```
  "vehicle":
  {
    "driver_id": 1,
    "make": "5000г",
    "model": "Merc",
    "plate_number": "AE 1111 AB"
  }
}
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Driver'
```

Comment: Do you have any serializers for Driver ?

Comment: where is your ```Driver``` class?

Comment: @ShashikamalRC no

Comment: @РоманЯровой can you please add full traceback?

Comment: You're doing something strange. Every model gets the id Field for free, automatically, in Django. You can configure the type of it in your settings.py. Doing this driver_id and using it in place of an object is going to cause unnecessary confusion

Comment: @alexakarpov but i can't figure out where i made a mistake

Comment: @shivankgtm Yeap)
https://pastebin.com/9L3RdUDs

Answer (score 1):

Mate, you have got quite a few things confused )

For starters, this line in *delete*:

```
    vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle.objects.all(), pk=vehicle_id)
```

should be

```
vehicle = get_object_or_404(Vehicle, pk=vehicle_id)
```

objects.all() gets you a whole quesryset, which you don't need here.

Next, this line in *create*:

validated_data['driver_id'] = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id'])

You already have driver_id in request's data. That what the client of your API wants to delete. There's absolutely no reason to reassign values in that validated_data dict. What's worse, you're doing this:

1. load Driver model instance from db by using driver_id from the API call. OK, makes sense. What doesn't make sense is why you are substituting driver_id and id. If you need to mirror id into another field in the model, then at least don't mutate it. But my guess is, you don't need this driver_id at all.
2. Then you are taking the *object* looked up by id (in db) = drived_id (in the request), and you assigned that object to the key 'driver_id' inside the dict - and then attempt to *create* a new instance which you have just looked up! Now *this* makes no sense.

Comment: "Next, this line in create:
validated_data['driver_id'] = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id'])" - Yes, but if I do not add this, but send the id directly, it will give an error that an instance Driver was expected but int was passed, when I output all the cars

Comment: That was a wrong thing to do - you have not fixed the problem, but obfuscated it and made it worse as a result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the id of your object so replace all occurences of the following :

```
instance.driver_id = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id'])
```

by

```
instance.driver_id = Driver.objects.get(id=validated_data['driver_id']).id
```

Comment: Yes, now it displays information on the object, but when I want to update the object and in driver_id specify a number, it throws an error ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Vehicle.driver_id" must be a "Driver" instance.

Comment: This is kinda funny. You have the Id, and look up the object in the database by that Id, and use that object to retrieve its..  Id? Wut? ))

Comment: @alexakarpov I have been at the computer for more than 6 hours and my head is already a mess, so for me it's not very funny))

Comment: @РоманЯровой "t throws an error ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Vehicle.driver_id" must be a "Driver" instance. "
 it is because in your Vehicle class you must have set driver_id in foreign key relation with Driver. can you also paste Vehicle class

Comment: @shivankgtm yeap, done)

Comment: @РоманЯровой you still haven't pasted the model class of Vehical. can you please make sure that all details are there which we need. in the question.

Comment: @shivankgtm Added model) The bottom line is that, under certain circumstances, I need to take cars with and without drivers.
Therefore, it is possible not to indicate the driver_id in the cars, if this car does not have a driver. And then I make a selection in the database, if I need to display cars without drivers, I select all cars where driver_id=null.

Comment: @shivankgtm updated information in the question

Comment: @РоманЯровой I want to help, but can't help if I ll keep getting information in bytes. I request you to kindly update the question with latest query. also keep the code of same file in same code block while pasting the code. Thanks